# Develop in the cloud, but Debug Android App on local device over USB over Remote Desktop

Tags: android, cloud, remote-debugging

I have been able to install Eclipse, with the android SDK, and get my android app to compile, **DEBUG** and run on a local desktop.

Now I would like to do the same, but over a connection to a **remote** desktop, basically a server in the cloud.

Any ideas on what is required to do this?  I am especially interested in debug.

I have tried just simply connecting the device and enabling it in remote settings.  Is there something else I need to enable/install?  Is there something I need to configure on the ADB bridge?

Comment: @Lucas B: It would help if you would define "remote desktop" in this circumstance. I usually think of a "remote desktop" as "one that is nowhere near me, that I am accessing via VNC/X/NX/RDP/whatever", which means I can't plug anything into it via USB.

Comment: @CommonsWare for me "remote desktop" is a piece of software, like RealVNC, or RemoteDesktopConnection, that comes with Windows.  I am hoping to plug my device in locally, and then debug it using a machine on the other end of a remote connection.  Is that more clear now?

Comment: @Lucas B Why don't you let the remote user **ssh** into your system.In that case he just needs to call `adb -d logcat` to see logs .

Comment: @Lucas B: You can't share the USB connection from your local pc to your remote pc, so you can't debug in that way... The only possible solution is do have the device plugged in at the remote pc, but than you probably can't access you device for testing... so it is, afaik, not possible

Comment: @WarrenFaith I am able to share the USB connection across to the remote pc, however, so far, I can only get it to appear as an additional drive and the adb does not recognize it.  I'm wondering if there is a way to force the adb to use it...

Comment: @lucas: I don't get it. Why would you like to develop with a remote pc and a real device. That suggest that the remote pc is near you. So why don't you skip the remote part and just develop directly on the pc?!

Comment: @Warren  Sorry for any confusion... basically, I have created a cloud server and am using RDC to connect to it,  I would like to be able to develop and DEBUG in the cloud rather than on my local machine.

Comment: Developing in the cloud: SSH session to a server, programming in vim or your favorite CLI editor, building and packaging from the command line, rsyncing the .apk locally and debugging locally. Done. What I'm trying to tell you is that it does not make any sense at all.

Comment: @Octavian I'm not sure what you are saying.  Are you discouraging this as a development path?  There are so many positive aspects of developing in the cloud rather than on a local pc, but that conversation is not appropriate here and is better on something like SuperUser

Comment: It is not a topic for any SE site but for the [Android Lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/520/android-lounge-no-so-questions). You're invited to join and discuss. ;)

Comment: I don't know Lucas B's exact use case, but I um...ran into [this somewhat related post that appeared in an AWS forum] (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=214581&#214581)

Comment: @lucas any updates, I'm trying to do exactly the same. I'll appreciate if you can share your progress.

Comment: @EfiMK I have been unable to progress any further with this.  Sorry.  :(

Answer (score 1):

This app may help:

[ADB port forward](https://code.google.com/p/adbportforward/)

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you mean using Eclipse to debug the application running on the device. If this is correct, [this documentation page](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-projects.html) may help.

Comment: thank you for this, but I am already aware of debugging with Eclipse.  I believe this may require some customization of the ADB.